# New financial tweet and news sentiment analysis dataset

Tags: data-request, social-media, sentiment-analysis

Are there any datasets that contains financial tweets or news title and their sentiment polarity (negative, neutral, and positive) that is labeled by humans?

The datasets that I find on the internet and mostly kaggle are not labeled by humans (which may have mistakes) or are very old like 2013.

Comment: Please link the dataset that are _not_ appropriate.